# Split into bytes, boolean pairs mutable

Tags: python

I'm trying to split a data file I opened into an array, each cell will contain 97 bytes of data + 3 bytes of the cell number. Now I want to add an additional boolean variable, but the problem here is changing that boolean value later as python treats my pair as a tuple.

```
def initialize():
    global data_arr, ack_arr, arr_size_bytes
    text = open(FILE_NAME, "rb")
    data = text.read()
    # Make new array of bytes from current file, to each segment add 3-byte long sequence number.
    data_arr = [(data[i:i + 97] + int((i / 97)).to_bytes(3, 'little')) for i in range(0, len(data), 97)]
    # Make new boolean array to hold acknowledgments received.
    ack_arr = [False for i in range(0, len(data_arr), 1)]
    text.close()
```

Instead of making a second array (`ack_arr`) I want somehow to create a pair that will be accessible by `data_arr[i][0/1]` but being also mutable.

Comment: You can write `ack_arr = [False]*len(data_arr)`.  Having it be a separate array is not necessarily a bad solution.  You would be better served to have both of those lists be members of a class, so you can control access to them through class functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a class architecture.  Note how globals are gone.

```
class Mydata:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        data = open(filename, "rb").read()
        # Make new array of bytes from current file, to each segment add 3-byte long sequence number.
        self.data_arr = [(data[i:i + 97] + int((i / 97)).to_bytes(3, 'little')) for i in range(0, len(data), 97)]
        # Make new boolean array to hold acknowledgments received.
        self.ack_arr = [False] * len(self.data_arr)

    def is_mutable(self,n):
        return self.ack_arr[n]

    def modify( self, index, value ):
        if not self.ack_arr[index]:
            print( "Index", index, "is not mutable")
            # Might raise an exception
        else:
            self.data_arr[index] = value
```

Comment: you don't explicitly close data, but otherwise I would definitely write something like this for this usecase

Comment: `data` is not a file, `data` is the contents.

Comment: yes indeed, hence the note about not closing---you *can't* close it, so it gets closed on deallocation.  You're not writing to the file, but the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) still suggest using a context manager in order to make sure it gets closed early in case something else throws later.  Just didn't wan't to suggest the open(thing).read() paradigm to new users without a warning about not leaving open files around.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you explicitly create a tuple:

```
data_arr = [
    (data[i:i + 97] + int((i / 97)).to_bytes(3, 'little')) 
    for i in range(0, len(data), 97)
    ]
```

Create a list instead:

```
data_arr = [
    [data[i:i + 97] + int((i / 97)).to_bytes(3, 'little')] 
    for i in range(0, len(data), 97)
    ]
```

Note that this might not be the most readable representation of you data, depending on what you do with it later.  You might at very least what to use a dict with sensible keynames (e.g. `{"data": ..., "flag": ...}`) or you might actually be better off with separate lists.